# I need a button that will make a certain tab in my .nav-tabs active

Tags: javascript, html

This is the tab that I wish to make active by clicking on a button i have somewhere else on the page:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i> System Manager</a>
                </li>
```

This is the button i want to click to make that tab active:

```
<div class="panel-body panel-primary">
 <h4>System Manager</h4>
   <p></p>
    <a href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary" 
     id="btnLearn1">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: This is a very poor quality question that shows little effort or research in solving the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not properly wording but I've been looking everywhere for an answer that gives specifics. I never learned JS so its all still a little confusing for me

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $('#btnLearn1').click(function(event) {
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"][data-toggle="tab"]').not('.btn').parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Im new to JS so please bare with me. I understand the first and second line apply the function to the button on click, but can you explain what how the 3rd line works

Comment: You should read up on jQuery selectors.  The documentation also explains the other functions used (e.g. .parent() and .addClass()).